# iOS(Objective-C) Crashed for EXC_BAD_ACCESS,when get and set a atomic Global variable in Multithreading

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, atomic, exc-bad-access

My app crashed, suspected to be caused by multi-threaded operation of an attribute in a singleton object.
So I wrote a small piece of code and successfully reproduced the problem, but I still couldn't understand it.
I have defined the property as @property, which is atomic. Why does it still crash when accessed by multiple threads? Below is my code snippet:

```objectivec
Audio.h
@interface Audio : NSObject
@property NSString *audioName;
@property NSString *audioData;
@end


Audio.m
#import "Audio.h"
@implementation Audio
- (instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _audioData = @"";
        _audioName = nil;
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

```objectivec
AudioManager.h
@interface AudioManager : NSObject
+(instancetype)shareInstance;
@property Audio *curAudio;
-(void) play;
-(void) clearCurAudio;
@end


AudioManager.m
#import "AudioManager.h"
@implementation AudioManager
static id sharedInstance = nil;
+(instancetype)shareInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t predicate;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
-(void) play {
    NSLog(@"Current Audio name : %@",_curAudio.audioName);
    NSLog(@"Current Audio name : %@",_curAudio.audioData);
    NSLog(@"Current Audio name : %@",_curAudio.audioName);//crahed here!
    NSLog(@"Current Audio name : %@",_curAudio.audioData);
}
-(void) clearCurAudio {
    _curAudio = nil;
}
@end
```

```objectivec
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    dispatch_queue_t thread1 = dispatch_queue_create("queue1", nil);
    dispatch_queue_t thread2 = dispatch_queue_create("queue2", nil);
    dispatch_queue_t thread3 = dispatch_queue_create("queue3", nil);
    
    dispatch_async(thread1, ^{
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            Audio *newAudio = [[Audio alloc] init];
            newAudio.audioName = @"na";
            [[AudioManager shareInstance] setCurAudio:newAudio];
        }
    });
    
//
    dispatch_async(thread2, ^{
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            [[AudioManager shareInstance] play];
        }
    });
//
    dispatch_async(thread3, ^{
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            AudioManager * audioManager = [AudioManager shareInstance];
            [[AudioManager shareInstance] clearCurAudio];
        }

    });
}
```

Here is the crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjWLd.png)

Comment: It's not so much that it's accessed by multiple threads as it is that one of those threads set it to nil.  The crash says you're trying to access 0x52 as an address, which is likely the offset of `audioName` within the object.

Comment: See [Is it thread-safe to read an instance variable while calling a setter from another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512366/is-it-thread-safe-to-read-an-instance-variable-while-calling-a-setter-from-anoth) and [Objective-C atomic property thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295354/objective-c-atomic-property-thread-safe)

Comment: I delete `_audioName = nil` and `_curAudio = nil`,but still crashed.

Comment: @Willeke thanks a lot, I use `self.curAudio.audioName` ,and it runs well,crash gone

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys,problem solved!!, as @Willeke posted.
use `self.curAudio` rather than `_curAudio`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, you should directly use ivars only in initializers. That's why you can't directly use ivars in Swift